# DCRaw says I should compile with -O4 in gcc. Does -O4 exist?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

I was looking at building DCRaw from the source.  On its web page it recommends that I build with one of the following lines.

```
Compile with "gcc -o dcraw -O4 dcraw.c -lm -ljasper -ljpeg -llcms2" or "gcc -o dcraw -O4 dcraw.c -lm -DNODEPS".
```

I have never heard of -O4 in gcc.  How is that different from -O3?

https://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/

Comment: Is google down? Not found the gcc homepage?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum level of optimizations with `gcc` is `-O3`. Using `-O4` (or `-O5`, `-O6`, ..., `-O9`) actually reverts to `-O3`. There is no guarantee theses options are supported or will behave differently in the future, so just use `-O3` for portability.

```
 gcc -c -Q -O3 --help=optimizers > /tmp/O3-opts
 gcc -c -Q -O4 --help=optimizers > /tmp/O4-opts
 diff -u /tmp/O3-opts /tmp/O4-opts
```

Comment: Only in gcc... I'm going to use `-O666` from now on!

Comment: `-O666` is a good option to trigger the famous t nasal demons.

Answer (score 0):

Currently `-O3` is the highest numbered option that actually adds flags. gcc's numbered optimization levels are cumulative. That is, `-O3` includes all the `-O2` flags and `-O2` includes all of the `-O1` flags. This leaves the door open for a future `-O4` that would include all of `-O3` plus more.

The actual flags are in the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) but I think you get a better insight from the [code itself](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/opts.c#L428-L529).